# What is the use of const rvalue references?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I stumbled on the following code, and as I understand it, it shows a const rvalue reference. What is the use of such a construct, and what do it gain over a normal const lvalue reference?

```
void foo(const bar&& b);
```

Comment: It's not even comparable to a "normal const lvalue reference". It does something different.

Comment: In short: basically none.